# Plotting aggregate data in R

Tags: r, plot, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a set of data that consists of 358 rock samples and their densities, p-wave velocities, and rock type (a category from 1-8).

I used the aggregate function to find the mean density for each rock type and mean p-wave velocity for each rock type.

```
dens = aggregate(SONIC_TXT$Density_g.cm3, by=list(SONIC_TXT$Rock_type), mean)
vel = aggregate(SONIC_TXT$P.WaveVelocity_km.sec, by=list(SONIC_TXT$Rock_type), mean)
```

I now want to plot the results of these on a scatterplot of the mean density of each rock type vs. mean p-wave velocity of each rock type.

My attempts were returned with errors saying I needed "finite limits". So I added limits to the plot function and got a plot with those limits and no points. I tried ggplot and got no error, but also just a "plot" with no axes/borders/points/anything at all.

Can anyone help me?

---

Edit: My attempts consisted of:

1. `plot(dens$vel)`

   Which resulted in:

   ```
       Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
   In addition: Warning messages:
   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
   3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
   4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
   ```
2. `plot(dens$vel, xlim = c(0, 50), ylim = c(0,50),ylab ='ylab', xlab='xlab')`

   Which resulted in:

   [image: This plot]
3. `matplot(dens, cbind(dens$x,vel$x),type="p",col=c("red","green"),pch=16)`

   Which resulted in: This plot, which is more along the lines of what I was aiming for. Except for the velocity values don't line up with rock type now.

   [image]

---

Edit 2:

```
> dens2
  Rock_type Density_g.cm3
1         1      2.633226
2         2      2.677167
3         3      2.774167
4         4      2.919500
5         5      2.823643
6         6      2.794964
7         7      3.006226
8         8      3.240798

> vel2
  Rock_type P.WaveVelocity_km.sec
1         1              5.640581
2         2              5.803310
3         3              5.691533
4         4              6.426667
5         5              5.828643
6         6              6.217643
7         7              6.715594
8         8              7.556798
```

Comment: Can we see those plot attempts to help resolve issues? Also, a few rows of your input can help.

Comment: My only real input besides the input in my post is uploading and attaching the data (SONIC_TXT, which is a text file with the data). 

And there are no plots to show. They are either errors or just a plot with nothing on it. (i.e. it is a box, with the correct limits on x and y axis and no points).

Comment: By attempts, I mean your plot code and surely you can edit your post with a few lines of the aggregate data frames -*dens* and *vel*. All it takes is copy and paste with code formatting `{}`.

Comment: @Parfait I have edited the original post to contain my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, there is no `vel` in `dens2`, and `dens2` is a data frame, not a vector.  Try this:

```
d <- data.frame(dens=dens2$Density_g.cm3, vel2=vel2$P.WaveVelocity_km.sec, 
                type=dens2$Rock_type)
windows()
  with(d, plot(dens, vel2, pch=as.character(type)))
```

[image]

---

*(See revision history for original answer, which was speculation, and is outdated now that there is a reproducible example.)*